# php5-fpm ignoring redis ini file completely

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, redis

I've installed php5 pecl extension with `pecl install redis`, added `extension=redis.so` to `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/21-redis.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/21-redis.ini`. Then I restarted `php5-fpm` and `nginx`.

Now `php -m | grep redis` shows me that redis was installed fine for cli, but `phpinfo` (using nginx) shows no redis and under `Additional .ini files parsed` lists:

> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/00-ioncube.ini,
>   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
>   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
>   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-json.ini,
>   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
>   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
>   /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-readline.ini

But the same dir contains 21-redis.ini, which for some reason gets ignored:

```
# ls -1 /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/
00-ioncube.ini
05-opcache.ini
10-mysqlnd.ini
10-pdo.ini
20-curl.ini
20-json.ini
20-mysql.ini
20-mysqli.ini
20-pdo_mysql.ini
20-readline.ini
21-redis.ini
```

Contents of that file are as expected:

```
# cat /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/21-redis.ini 
extension=redis.so
```

And it's world-readable.

`/var/log/php5-fpm.log` has no errors, and neither does `/var/log/syslog`.

Why does not `php-fpm` load redis extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was because `php5-fpm` master process died, but workers did not. `service php5-fpm restart` did not update them.

I killed the remaining workers manually and restarted php-fpm again. Now it all works.

Comment: I had a similar problem. For me it was that the `php-fpm` process hadn't been restarted after installing the database package.